# Proving closure under reversal of languages accepted by min-heap automata

Tags: formal-languages, automata, closure-properties

*This is a follow-up question of [this one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/110/98).*

In a previous question about [exotic state machines](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/110/69), Alex ten Brink and Raphael addressed the computational capabilities of a peculiar kind of state machine: min-heap automata. They were able to show that the set of languages accepted by such machines ($HAL$) is neither a subset nor a superset of the set of context-free languages. Given the successful resolution of and apparent interest in that question, I proceed to ask several follow-up questions.

It is known that the regular languages are closed under a variety of operations (we may limit ourselves to basic operations such as union, intersection, complement, difference, concatenation, Kleene star, and reversal), whereas the context-free languages have different closure properties (these are closed under union, concatenation, Kleene star, and reversal).

> Is HAL closed under reversal?

Comment: What are the uses of such machines? Or is this an academic exercise?

Comment: @DaveClark Well, they're mostly an academic exercise (as far as I know, I just made them up in the linked question). However, they can do computation in the same way that other machines (DFAs, TMs, etc.) can, so maybe there could be a use for them.

Comment: This question illustrates why you want to have grammars accompanying your automata. Arr, my brain!

Comment: I was trying to prove it by using a language of the format $\{xy \mid y\text{ is a lexicographically sorted copy of } x\}$, but it took too long and I gave up. Maybe this idea would help anybody.

Comment: @RanG.: I think that should work. I am happy to award the bounty to an answer that proves that the language is in $\mathrm{HAL}$ and gives a decent reasoning that the reversal is not.

Comment: @RanG I am similarly happy to select as an answer a sufficiently motivated (even if not formally rigorous) argument. I have made some modest attempts as answering this question myself, but have not met with success.

Comment: Note that the answer to this question might depend on whether heap symbols of same priority are accessed non-deterministically or in a (maybe unknown) deterministic way.

Comment: @RanG If the alphabet size is two then the language and its reverse are context-free.

Comment: @Yuval: I don't think so, $\{0^n 1^m 0^n 1^m\}$ is not context-free.

Comment: @Raphael Interesting... that being said, is any generality lost by simply assuming all heap symbols have distinct priorities? That may be a silly question... it's been a while since we introduced these things ;D

Comment: I *think* "classic" type-1 HAL is not hurt by distinct priorities (I have conjectured elsewhere that they can essentially do one counter per priority). Type-2 HAL is certainly neutered; you can not utilise the stack property at all, collapsing type-2 and type-1. If the heap is nondeterministic, you lose power for the same reason.

Comment: sdcvvc is right, my method only shows that the likes of $\{ 0^a 1^b 0^c 1^d : a+c = b+d \}$ are context-free.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the language 
$$L_{\times 2} = \big\{ x\bot y\bot z  \mid x,y,z\in \{0,1\}, \#_0(x)=\#_0(y) \text{ and } |x|+|y|=z\big \}$$
(where $\#_0(x)$ denotes the number of zeros in $x$).

It is easy to decide $L_{\times 2}$ using a HAL machine — observe that the machine needs to keep track of two properties: the number of zeros in $x$ vs $y$ and the length of $x,y$ (vs $z$). It can push a `0` into the heap for every zero it sees in $x$ (and then later pop `0` for any zero seen in $y$); additionally it pushes `1` for any bit in $x,y$ (and later pops `1` for any bit of $z$). Since all the `1`s are pushed down the heap, they don't interfere with the `0` count. The $\bot$ serves as a delimiter, and can be practically ignored.

Now, let $L = L_{\times 2}^R$, be the reverse language. That is,
$$ L = \big\{z\bot y \bot x \mid  x,y,z\in \{0,1\}, \#_0(x)=\#_0(y) \text{ and } |x|+|y|=z\big \}$$
We will show that no HAL machine can decide $L$.

The intuition is the following. As above, the machine must keep track of both the length of $z$ and the number of zeros in $x,y$. However, in this case it need to track them *simultaneously*. This cannot be done via a heap. In more details, after reading $z$, the heap contains information about the length of $|x|+|y|$.
while reading $y$ the machine must also keep in the heap the number of zeros in $y$. However, this information cannot interfere with the information the heap already has on the length we expect $x$ to be. Very intuitively, either the information about the number of zeros will be "below"  the information about the length of $x$, and then we cannot access it while reading $x$, or it is "above" that information, rendering the latter inaccessible, or the two information will be "mixed" and become meaningless.

More formally, we are going use some kind of a "pumping" argument. That is, we will take a very long input, and show that the "state" of the machine must repeat itself during processing that input, which will allow us to "replace" the input once the machine repeats its "state".

For the formal proof, we require a simplification of the structure of the HAL machine, namely, that it doesn't contain a "loop" of $\varepsilon$-transitions$^1$. With this assumption we can see that for every input symbol the machine processes, the content of the heap can increase/decrease by at most $c$  (for some large enough constant $c$).

*Proof.*
Assume $H$ decides $L$, and consider a long enough input (say, of length $4n$, thus $|x|=|y|=n$, $|z|=2n$, ignoring the $\bot$s hereinafter). To be concrete, fix $z,y$ and assume that $\#_0(y) = n/2$. Observe that there are ${n \choose n/2}$ different $x$'s such that $z\bot y \bot x \in L$.

Consider the heap's content immediately after processing $z\bot y$. It contains at most $3nc$ symbols (where each symbol is from a fixed alphabet $\Gamma$), by our assumption. However, there are ${n \choose n/2}$ different $x's$ that should be accepted (which is substantially larger than the amount of possible different contents for the heap, as this increases exponentially, while the different number of heaps increases polynomially, see below). 
Take two inputs $x_1,x_2$ that should be accepted, so that the following holds:

1. The prefix of length $n/2$ of $x_1$ has different number of zeros than the prefix of $x_2$ of the same length.
2. By the time the machine reads a prefix of  length $n/2$ of the $x$ part, the heap looks the same for both $x_1$ and $x_2$, and also, the machine is in the same state  (this must happen for some $x_1,x_2$, for large enough $n$, as there are more than $2^{0.8n}$ different options$^2$ for $x_1,x_2$, and at most $(3.5cn)^{|\Gamma|}|Q|$ different options for heap content and state$^3$).

It is clear that the machine must accept the word $z\bot y \bot x_1^px_2^s$, where $x_1^p$ is a prefix of $x$ of length $n/2$ and $x_2^s$ is a suffix of $x_2$ of the same length. Note that the number of zeros in $x_1^px_2^s$ differs from the number of zeros in $x_1$ and $x_2$ (that is, from $\#_0(y)$), due to the way we chose $x_1$ and $x_2$, thus we reached a contradiction.

$^1$  <sup>Does this assumption damages generality? I don't think so, but this indeed requires a proof. If someone sees how to get around this extra assumption, I'd love to know.</sup>
$^2$  <sup>Let's fix $x_1$ so that it's prefix (of length $n/2$ has exactly $n/4$ zeros). Recall that using [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas) we know that $\log {n \choose k} \approx nH(k/n)$ where $H()$ is the [Binary entropy funciton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_entropy_function). Since $H(1/4) \approx 0.81$ we have ${n \choose n/4} > 2^{0.8n}$ for large enough $n$.</sup>
$^3$  <sup>Assuming alphabet $\Gamma$, there are $|\Gamma|^n$ different strings of length $n$, so if this was a stack we were screwed. However, pushing "01" into a heap is equivalent to pushing "10" - the heap stores only the sorted version of the content. The number of different *sorted* strings of size $n$ is  ${n+1 \choose |\Gamma|-1}\approx n^{|\Gamma|}$, for a constant $|\Gamma|$.</sup>

Comment: Nice! Will have to read the formal part again later. 1) Ad ¹: See also [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2338/how-to-prove-that-loops-are-not-necessary-in-pdas). 2) The argument breaks down if we allow non-deterministic choice of the returned heap symbol (among all symbols of the same priority).