# Is a PDA's stack size linear bounded in input size?

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata

I was thinking as follows: At each step, a PDA can put arbitrary many symbols onto the stack. But this number is constant for every individual PDA, so it can't be more than, say, $k$ symbols per step. Using only regular transitions, the stack can rise to maximally (more or less) $kn$ symbols in a run on an input sized $n$.

But what about $\epsilon$-transitions? Is there a simple argument why their maximum number should as well be independent of the input size?

So, in short: Is a PDA's stack size linear in the input size?

Comment: I *think* this is a [duplicate](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2338/how-to-prove-that-%CE%B5-loops-are-not-necessary-in-pdas?rq=1) of my older question. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, it's fine by me to mark the question as duplicate. Yours is far more specific and covers mine. (PS. I have basically no internet connection due to moving, so I can't really join the discussion; I hope at least this comment will be sent... But thanks a lot for the interesting suggestions. I wouldn't have thought this to be so hard.)
Btw. Is it any different for DPDA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. In NPDAs, you can have cycles of $\varepsilon$-transitions that add symbols to the stack. Thus the stack content can be unbounded.

Proving that CFL ⊆ CSL via automata is [tough](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2338/how-to-prove-that-%CE%B5-loops-are-not-necessary-in-pdas); the trusted route via grammars seems advised.

Comment: I think that if you allow the (bounded) stack size to be a function $f(n)$ of the input length (as Lukas said in the question) and the non-deterministc branches that cause a "stack overflow" are simply discarded, then for each NPDA $A$ there is an equivalent $f_A(n)$-NPDA $A'$ that recognizes the same language (though the function $f$ is probably not linear). I'll search for references ...

Comment: @Vor Knowing that every CFL has a Greibach normal form, the standard textbook construction yields an NPDA with linearly bounded stack (iirc). The *existence* of such an NPDA for every CFL is therefore not surprising, but it's completely unclear (to me) how to get there (more easily than Zetzsche's technique, which I can not claim to fully grasp anyway) directly from an arbitrary NPDA.

Comment: I wanted to avoid the detour over grammers as my students at this point don't know them yet. But I get now that it's not a good idea... ;-)