# Computational power of deterministic versus nondeterministic min-heap automata

Tags: formal-languages, automata, nondeterminism

*This is a follow-up question of [this one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/110/98).*

In a previous question about [exotic state machines](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/110/69), Alex ten Brink and Raphael addressed the computational capabilities of a peculiar kind of state machine: min-heap automata. They were able to show that the set of languages accepted by such machines ($HAL$) is neither a subset nor a superset of the set of context-free languages. Given the successful resolution of and apparent interest in that question, I proceed to ask several follow-up questions.

It is known that deterministic and nondeterministic finite automata have equivalent computational capabilities, as do deterministic and nondeterministic Turing machines. However, the computational capabilities of deterministic push-down automata are less than those of nondeterministic push-down automata.

> Are the computational capabilities of deterministic min-heap automata less than, or are they equal to, those of nondeterministic min-heap automata?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that for this model, non-deterministic machines are not equivalent to deterministic ones, for basically the same reason that deterministic PDAs are not equivalent to non-deterministic ones.

Consider the language
$$L =\\{ x\$y \mid |x|=|y| \wedge x\ne y\\}$$
(where $\$$ is a special sign not contained in $x$ and $y$).

I claim that a non-deterministic machine $N$-$HAL$ can decide this language: It performs the same as the PDA for $L$. The standard PDA solution uses the stack only to count offsets: it nondeterministically guesses an offset $i$, remembers the value of $x_i$ (adding a symbol to the stack at each step), then the PDA ignores the input until it find the $\$$, and then it pops symbols out of the stack until it is empty. At this stage we are exactly at $y_i$ and he PDA can check if $x_i \ne y_i$. (if anything goes wrong in the middle, the PDA "dies"). 
Since the stack alphabet is unary, it can be simulated with a min-heap machine. 
Actually: any $L$ that is is accepted by a PDA with a unary alphabet can be accepted by a min-heap machine. (I'm ignoring, maybe, another special sign added to identify an empty stack, but an equivalent sign can be added to the heap)

For the other direction, I don't have the formal proof, but here are my thoughts:

I claim that a deterministic machine $D$-$HAL$ is incapable of deciding this language. Intuitively, the content of the heap can not be correlated with $x$ (otherwise, permute $x$. the content of the heap remains the same..). This suggests that only thing that matters is the number of elements in the heap, but then, if $D$-$HAL$ can decide $L$, so can a deterministic-$PDA$.

**Edit:** more details about the "permute $x$" claim. Assuming Raphael's [conjecture](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/115/157) 
there exist $x_1$ and $x_2$ that after reading them, the content of the heap is the same.
Then consider the words $x_1\$x_1$ and $x_2\$x_1$. The content of the heap is the same when the HAL gets to the dollar sign, thus it must either accept both or reject both. **contradiction**.

anyone sees an immediate proof for the conjecture?

Comment: While I think your are basically right, it is not as easy as saying "otherwise, permute $x$. the content [...] remains the same.". A HA (or PDA) *can* take patterns of constant length into account.

Comment: Which definition of min-heaps are you using: my original one, or the more natural one suggested by Raphael? In either case, can you be more clear about how a nondeterministic machine would accept the language you give... what does it put onto and take off of the heap, and when?

Comment: Doesn't Raphael's conjecture directly follow from a counting argument? While there are exponentially many strings of length $n$, the number of possible configurations (heap + state) is only polynomial in $n$, since the total number of symbols in the heap is linear and the number of different symbols is constant.