# Is a stack machine with a forward read iterator Turing complete?

Tags: computation-models, turing-completeness, linked-lists, stacks

It is well known that a machine with a single stack as only unlimited storage is not Turing complete, if it can only read from the top of the stack. I want a machine which is (slightly) more powerful than a stack machine, but still not Turing complete. (I wonder whether there exists a non-Turing complete machine, which can deterministically simulate any non-deterministic pushdown automata with an only polynomial slow-down.) The most benign (straightforward) extension that came to my mind was a (single) forward read iterator.

Let me elaborate the implementation details, to make it clear what I mean by a forward read iterator. A [singly linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly_linked_list) can be used for implementing a stack. Let the list be implemented by a pointer `pTop`, which is either zero, or points to an `SList` node. An `SList` node consists of a payload field `value` and a pointer field `pNext`, where `pNext` is either zero, or points to an `SList` node. Let the forward read iterator be implemented by a pointer `pRead`, which is either zero, or points to an `SList`node. The pointers `pTop` and `pRead` cannot be accessed directly, but can only be used via the following methods:

- `Push(val)` creates a new `SList` node `n` with `n.value = val` and `n.pNext = pTop`, and sets `pTop = &n`.
- `Pop()` aborts if `pTop == 0` or `pRead == pTop`. Otherwise it reads `val = pTop->value` and `pTopNext = pTop->pNext`, frees the `SList` node pointed to by `pTop`, sets `pTop = pTopNext` and returns `val`.
- `ReadBegin()` sets `pRead = pTop`.
- `ReadNext()` aborts if `pRead == 0`. Otherwise it reads `val = pRead->value`, sets `pRead = pRead->pNext` and returns `val`.
- `ReadFinished()` returns `true` if `pRead == 0`, and `false` otherwise.

Comment: I should clarify that initially `pTop == 0` and `pRead == 0`. A method `ReadCancel()` which sets `pRead = 0` might also be a good idea, because otherwise the abort of `Pop()` for `pRead == pTop` might be annoying.

Comment: Between the pushdown automata and the Turing machines in the [Chomsky hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) sits the Linear-bounded non-deterministic Turing machine, corresponding to _context-sensitive language_.

Comment: There are automata with a stack of stacks, but I forgot the name. Also, I remember our ["homebrew" heap automata](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/110/determining-capabilities-of-a-min-heap-or-other-exotic-state-machines).

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel just a heads up that there was a mistake in my answer, but not a catastrophic one, you're still clear from Turing completeness, but your model is a little more powerful than I first thought (I misinterpreted the non-erasing property, in a really dumb way in hindsight).

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel, a second heads up, user23013 is correct (see his answer), your model is Turing complete - the clincher is that you have two pointers into the stack, whereas Stack Automata only have one (so it can move around the stack, but can only pop/push at the top).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your model is Turing-complete, unfortunately.

You can simulate a queue in your data structure using the following algorithm. It introduced 3 new stack symbols: $d, x, y$.

`Enqueue(val)` is just `Push(val)`.

For `Dequeue()`:

1. `ReadBegin()`.
2. Count the number of anything else - number of $d$ in the whole stack (which should be always non-negative). Push $y$ or pop $x$ for every $d$, and push $x$ or pop $y$ for anything else. Always prefer pop to push. Finally there won't be any $y$ in the stack and the result will be the number of $x$ on the top of the stack.
3. `ReadBegin()`.
4. While `pTop` is a $x$:

   1. Repeat `ReadNext()` until it returned something other than $x$ and $d$.
   2. `Pop()`.
5. Push a $d$.
6. The last result of `ReadNext()` is returned as the result of `Dequeue`.

The proof is straightforward. Check the revision history for a more complicated version firstly reducing it to a two-way version.

Comment: Found the difference, you are correct, the OP's model is Turing complete. A Stack Automaton doesn't have a second read head to scan the stack, it can  just move its normal head up and down, but can only push at the top.

Answer (score 5):

Your model is Turing complete (unlike what I previously thought), see user23013's answer a sketch of the proof (the essence is you can simulate a queue, and queue automata are Turing complete).

There are several ways to weaken you model to drop to equivalence with linear bound automata or lower.

Ginsburg, Greibach & Harrison [1] give a machine called a "Stack Automaton" which is a PDA with two additional capabilities:

1. The input head can move left an right (so it can scan previously seen parts of the input).
2. The read/write head on the stack can scan through the stack in read-only mode, but pushing and popping still only occur at the top. Note the key difference here with your model, which confused me earlier: the stack only has one head/pointer that it can move up and down the stack, whereas yours has two, which is enough to make your model Turing complete.
   They also give another model [2], where the input can only be read left-to-right, but the additional read-only stack scanning is still available.

In Figure 2 of [1] they give the containment (proved in Section 5 of the same, perhaps with some parts in [2]) and two-way nondeterministic stack automata languages are strictly contained in $\mathrm{R}$. However they are equivalent to nondeterministic linear bound automata, so they recognise context sensitive-languages.

Two-way and nondeterministic stack automata and two-way deterministic stack automata seem to be equivalent, however changing the input head to one-way makes a significant difference. The set of one-way nondeterministic stack automata languages is a strict subset of context-sensitive languages (I can't put my finger on exactly where yet), and the set of one-way deterministic stack automata (which are equivalent to your model) languages is a strict subset of the set of one-way nondeterministic stack automata languages.

A weaker type again, which falls below these are non-erasing stack automata, which can only write to the stack.

Hopcroft & Ullman show that the languages recognised by non-erasing deterministic stack automata corresponds to $\mathrm{DSPACE}(n\log n)$ and non-erasing nondeterministic stack automata corresponds to $\mathrm{DSPACE}(n^{2})$.

**Addendum**

After some more digging, [these lecture slides](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506225944/http://www.frontiersinai.com/turingfiles/September/andreasmalcher.pdf) suggest that one-way non-erasing deterministic stack automata are strictly weaker than the two-way version, so recognise something less than $\mathrm{DSPACE}(n\log n)$.

I also found further Hopcroft & Ullman [4,5] papers, which may provide a few more clues, but it seems to be tangential at this point. [5] at least proves some equivalences of some Stack Automata with LBAs.

**References**

1. Seymour Ginsburg, Sheila A. Greibach and Michael A. Harrison, "Stack Automata and Compiling". Journal of the ACM, 14(1):172–201, 1967.
2. Seymour Ginsburg, Sheila A. Greibach and Michael A. Harrison, "One-Way Stack Automata". Journal of the ACM, 14(2):389–418, 1967.
3. John E. Hopcroft, Jeffrey D. Ullman, ["Nonerasing Stack Automata"](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022000067800138/1-s2.0-S0022000067800138-main.pdf?_tid=501b9a72-e052-11e4-aba2-00000aab0f27&acdnat=1428760666_523813f575113ea1d627b50d6374dc9e). JCSS, 1(2):166–186, 1967.
4. John E. Hopcroft, Jeffrey D. Ullman, ["Deterministic Stack Automata and the Quotient Operator"](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022000068800030/1-s2.0-S0022000068800030-main.pdf?_tid=619a2da2-e054-11e4-91a6-00000aab0f6c&acdnat=1428761554_fd021b3303d9c83e2ada375c041c17bb), JCSS, 2:1-12, 1968.
5. John E. Hopcroft, Jeffrey D. Ullman, ["Two results on one-way stack automata"](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5397225), Symposium on Switching and Automata Theory (SWAT - but not that SWAT), 1967.

Comment: But the model in this question isn't non-erasing, which should be equivalent to its two-way version (by recording and counting push/pop/up/down operations in the stack).

Comment: @user23013 correct, I misinterpreted the non-erasing part.

Comment: Just tried to see why my conclusion doesn't agree with yours, and I'm convinced that this model is in fact Turing complete now. To confirm: where does it say the two-way stack automaton cannot use the stack as a queue (set the extra pointer at the bottom and never moving down)? If it is forbidden somehow, I think that isn't specified in this question.

Comment: @user23013 the second pointer is read only, there's no operation to add anything where `pRead` is. (as I understand it)

Comment: But `pTop` and `pRead` are two separate pointers. You can enqueue at `pTop` and dequeue (by moving up and ignore anything below) at `pRead`? (If it is two-way.)

Comment: @user23013 that's shouldn't be enough for Turing completeness though, you need to be able to overwrite things in the middle of the stack/queue.

Comment: Huh? Isn't [automaton with only a queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_automaton) Turing complete?

Comment: Yes, yes it is... Hmmm. That would also conflict with the Stack Automaton paper's results. This requires some more thinking.